# How do I fade in borders of an image in html canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl, webgl2

How can I fade in borders of an image in canvas (webgl).

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve:

[image]

Initially I was trying to use canvas filtering `filter: blur(8px)` however it blurs the entire image.
But I want to have only blurred edges of the shape.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS masking to do that.

First create a blurred white and black image, where the white is opaque and the black fully transparent. Then use it in the [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) CSS attribute like this:

```
img {
  mask: url(my-mask.jpg);
}
```

Here is a working example: https://codepen.io/tolokoban/full/xxyXaKR

We used a SVG instead of a bitmap image to create the mask, but that's the same technique in the end.